# What is loss if Rs to the fruit seller?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A fruit seller sold a basket of fruits at 12.5% loss. Had he sold it for Rs. 108 more, he
>   would have made a 10% gain. What is the loss in Rupees incurred by the fruit seller?
>
> $a) \ 48\quad $  $b) \ 50\quad $  $c) \ 60\quad $ $d) \ 108\quad $

Let $CP$ and $SP$ be the cost price and selling price respectively then

first condition $$\frac{12.5}{100}=\frac{CP-SP}{CP}\implies SP=0.875 CP$$
2nd condition $$\frac{SP+108-CP}{CP}=\frac{10}{100}$$
$$\frac{SP}{CP}+\frac{108}{CP}-1=0.1$$
$$0.875+\frac{108}{CP}=1.1\implies CP=480$$
now loss in rs
$$=\frac{12.5}{100}\times CP=\frac{12.5}{100}\times 480=60$$

I am not sure if my answer is correct. Can anyone give other simpler method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the cost of the Basket and $B$ be the cost of the basket at 12.5% loss.

$B=X\times 0.875$

$B+108=1.1 \times X$

Solving for $X$: $$X\times 0.875+108=X \times 1.1$$

It is trivial to show $X=480$ and loss is $60$ as you have given :)